# Modify a window that will be opened

Tags: javascript

I would like to open a window when I click on a button and modify the html and css of the page that will be open. How can I do this?

I work on a symfony project and I just want to write on a paragraph of the window that will be opened. So for this I tried:

```
$( "#tom" ).click(function() { 
  var wind = window.open("{{ path('AjoutFournisseur') }}", "Ajouter un fournisseur", "width=520,height=1080");
  wind.document.getElementById("can").innerHTML='TEST'; 
});
```

And I have this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at
>   HTMLSpanElement. (add-volet:113) at
>   HTMLSpanElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2) at HTMLSpanElement.y.handle
>   (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive than "it didn't work"?  Did it give you an error?  What actually happened?  `getElementbYId` is not valid, btw.  Is that a typo in your question?

Comment: I work on a symfony project and i just want to write on a paragraph of the window that will be opened. So for this i use : $( "#tom" ).click(function() {
        var wind = window.open("{{ path('AjoutFournisseur') }}", "Ajouter un fournisseur", "width=520,height=1080");
        wind.document.getElementById("can").innerHTML='TEST';
    }); And i have this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at HTMLSpanElement.<anonymous> (add-volet:113)
    at HTMLSpanElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLSpanElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I've moved the code from your comment into the question; in future please add information by editing the question itself rather than posting it in comments; unformatted code in comments can be hard to read and is easy for other users to miss)

Answer (score 1):

If the popup window is not on the same domain as the parent window, this will not be possible without cooperation from the other site (CORS rules and the same-origin policy will apply).

If both pages are on the same domain, the change you need to make is to wait for the popup window to finish loading before trying to modify it; right now you're opening the window and then immediately trying to change its contents before the network request has had a chance to return them.

I can't demonstrate this within a functioning stack overflow snippet, because it won't allow popup windows, but this is what it would look like:

```
$('#tom').on("click", function() {
  let thePopup = window.open("url_of_popup_window.html");
  thePopup.onload = function(e) {
    thePopup.document.getElementById("can").innerHTML = 'TEST';
    // Or, since you're already using jQuery, use this equivalent to the above line:
    // $('#can', e.target).html('TEST'); // e.target is the popup document here
    // (this would be usable even if jQuery is not in the popup window, because this script runs in the parent)
  }
});
```